# Can an EU residence permit be rescinded with no notification to the holder?

Tags: austria

As described in the title of the question, I am asking if a residence permit already issued to a third-country national by an EU country (in my case, Austria) can be rescinded or invalidated remotely, without any notification.

I have applied for and received a residence permit with type "**Student**", one of the necessary conditions for the initial application at the consulate was the possession of an admission letter from an Austrian university - I have submitted it and was approved, then issued a visa D with remarks **"ABH.AT"** and **"FP"**.

Upon coming to Austria, I had to attend two appointments and present papers confirming my current enrollment at the university I was accepted to.

During both appointments and in an e-mail I stated that I can not be enrolled **until a later date** and asked for the appointment to be scheduled after I have enrolled (but before my visa expires) - there was no clear or explicit communication about the authority's reasoning, but my permit was first personalised/printed and at a later appointment, handed to me with all documents shown except for the enrollment papers.

The core of my question is - in cases like these, can my residence permit be invalidated? Should I assume an exception was made and is contacting the authority again for clarifications necessary?